# Unknown bug affecting Graham's algorithm for finding convex hull

Tags: c++, math, computational-geometry

I have programmed the Graham's algorithm but it still gives me the wrong points for the convex hull. I need help. Think I have a bug in my sign function but dunno what it is.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <pair<double, double> > st;
pair<double, double> p[1000];
double x, y;

int f(pair <double,double> a, pair<double, double> b)
{
    double x1 = x - a.first, x2 = x - b.first;
    double y1 = y - a.second, y2 = y - b.second;    
    return ((x1*y2-y1*x2) < 0);
}

void setlast(double &x1, double &y1, double &x2, double &y2)
{    
    x2 = st[st.size()-1].first;
    y2 = st[st.size()-1].second;
    x1 = st[st.size()-2].first;
    y1 = st[st.size()-2].second;
}
```

sign improved I use doubles

```
    double sign(double x1,double y1, double x2,double y2, double y3,double x3)
    {
        double xx1 = x2 - x1, xx2 = x3 - x1;
        double yy1 = y2 - y1, yy2 = y3 - y1;
        return (xx1*yy2-yy1*xx2);
    }

int main()
{    
    int n;
    x = 0x3f3f3f3f;
    y = 0x3f3f3f3f;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &p[i].first, &p[i].second);
        if(p[i].first <= x && p[i].second <= y)
            x = p[i].first,
            y = p[i].second;
    }
    sort(p, p + n, f);
    p[n].first = x;
    p[n].second = y;
    st.pb(mp(p[0].first, p[0].second));
    st.pb(mp(p[1].first, p[1].second));
    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
```

here I iterate through all vectors and try to determine the points of convex hull

```
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        x3 = p[i].first;
        y3 = p[i].second;
        setlast(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        while(1)
            if(sign(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) < 0)
            {
                st.pb(mp(x3, y3));
                break;
            }
            else
                st.pop_back(),
                setlast(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
```

here printing the convex hull

```
for(int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++)
        printf("%lf %lf\n", st[i].first, st[i].second);
    return 0
}
```

Comment: In `int f(pair...)`, you should not use `abs`, that produces the wrong sort order.

Comment: My question, why does `int f(pair<int, int>, pair<int, int>)` take `pair<int, int>` instead of `pair<double, double>`? Also, why isn't it named something information like `compare_blah`? Lastly, why doesn't it return `bool` instead of an `int`? The `pair<int, int>` thing could be your problem right there. You are doing several implicit type conversions in that function between `int` and `double` and losing information left and right. I doubt that's what you intended.

Comment: Ohh.. Yeess.. I think I found that error when checking my sign function but forgot to update it in f(). I will try it now. Thanks!

Comment: I think that all of what you stated except the bool function type I have to correct. You know returning int or bool is not a big matter because int also will return 1 or 0 which is true or false. I think that pair<int, int> is the actual error. Thank you! I will try to fix it now.

Comment: @Tahir: It's a matter of being clear about what you're doing, of coding style, not strictly whether or not the program functions the way you want it to. If you return an `int` it's not at all clear that the function is intended to answer a simple yes/no question until you read it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

My question, why does `int f(pair<int, int>, pair<int, int>)` take `pair<int, int>` instead of `pair<double, double>`?

Also, why isn't it named something informative like `compare_blah`?

Lastly, why doesn't it return `bool` instead of an `int`? Either works of course, but it will be clearer that this is intended simply as a comparison function if you return a `bool`. And making your program clear to people who read it should be your primary goal. Getting it to do what it's supposed to is a secondary goal. After all, it doing what it's supposed to is only a transitory state of affairs. Eventually someone will want it to do something else.

The `pair<int, int>` thing could be your problem right there. You are doing several implicit type conversions in that function between `int` and `double` and losing information left and right. I doubt that's what you intended.

If you would use a typedef for your `pair` like `typedef pair<double, double> point2d_t` and then use `point2d_t` everywhere you could protect yourself from mistakes like that and make your program clearer in the bargain.

I'm not familiar enough with Graham's algorithm to evaluate your use of `abs` inside of `f`, though it's quite possible the person who commented on this is correct.

Comment: why i didn't name it something informative is because I wanted to save time and wrote this task for Olympiad. So, I have some standart and short labels for some function like comparison for stl sort. Thank you!

Comment: @Tahir: Ahh. Well, that does make some sense (I've competed in an event like that myself). Though I will argue that you are more likely to write correct code the first time if you write the code as if you're explaining to someone else how it works.

Comment: Ohh, Well you are right probably. I just did not think about it when posting the code. Thanks!